# Import Error: cannot import pivot_simple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Ubuntu system with python 2.7  and pandas version of 0.19.I have been trying to run a python file and this error keeps on showing up-

```
>>> import file.py as x  
   Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
   File "file.py", line 4, in <module>  
   import pandas as pd
   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py",      line 39, in <module>
   from pandas.core.api import *   
   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py",  line 20, in <module>
   from pandas.core.reshape import (pivot_simple as pivot, get_dummies,  
   ImportError: cannot import name pivot_simple
```

Please help me in resolving the issue by telling the possible issues for this error and the way it can be removed.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried updating pandas

Comment: @HariKrishnan I am bound to use the same version of pandas :(

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'files.py'
please try 'import files as x'

Comment: Could you expand on your answer, explaining how it solves the issue? If this is just a comment or a guess than it might not belong into an answer. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/266197 specifically the section `Can I put my comment in an answer?`